# mysqlfailover automatic failover is not enabled

Tags: mysql, replication

i use mysqlfailover

> mysqlfailover --master=root@132.232.142.73:3306
>   --discover-slaves-login=root --slaves=root@12.32.53.2:3306 --report-values=health --verbose  --failover-mode=auto --log=failoverlog.txt

it report

> Attempting to contact 132.232.142.73 ... Success   Attempting to
>   contact 12.32.53.2 ... Success  Replication Health Status  0 Rows
>   Found.

it connect to 12.32.53.2 success,but Replication Health Status 0 Rows Found. 
when i shutdown master,it report 
Failed to reconnect to the master after 3 attemps. 
ERROR: Master has failed and automatic failover is not enabled. Check server for errors and run the mysqlrpladmin utility to perform manual failover.

what is automatic failover is not enabled? why Replication Health Status 
0 Rows Found. please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the failover mode 'auto'. Eg:

> mysqlfailover --master=root@132.232.142.73:3306 --discover-slaves-login=root --slaves=root@12.32.53.2:3306 --report-values=health --verbose --log=failoverlog.txt **auto**

Hope this helps.